# Is there a way to submit in Chrome Browser without Button?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to force a submit for debugging purposes. Is there a way to submit a form in Chrome without javascript or jquery through developer tools?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Why can't you use JavaScript from inside the Developer Tools?

Comment: could you run something in the console like:

Comment: i tried $('#formName').submit(); the console just showed the form element

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open development tool and set in watch window the following

```
$('form').submit();
```

(you need to reference jquery library on page)

Comment: If you have anything that listens for onsubmit events, doing this will not fire it. But other than that this should work fine.

Answer (score 8):

In plain JavaScript, type this in the location/address bar (or in the console without the protocol prefix)

```
javascript:document.forms[indexOrName].submit();
```

e.g.

```
javascript:document.forms[0].submit();//first form
javascript:document.forms['myForm'].submit();//form by name
```

Comment: Yup. Or sticking with the jQuery he tried, `$('#formName')[0].submit();`